# how to access more then one database table on aspx page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

i m creating a mvc website in which i want to access  more then one table through videwdata.model, how can i do like this or it can do by another way.plz help me

Answer (score 2):

Views/ASPX pages shouldn't access database. They should only work with the view model which is passed by the controller. Neither the controller should know anything about a database. It uses a service layer which fetches data from somewhere (in your case multiple databases) and returns a model object. In the specific implementation of the service you could perform multiple queries from different databases.

Answer (score 0):

You can write multiple linq querys that access the tables you want.